# How do I imitate "Display Filter" property search with python?

Tags: python

I'm displaying items in an UIList which represent values in the "Properties" tabs. Now, I would like to add an operator which lets the user jump to the highlighted property (be it - Render Engine: Eevee) selected in the UIList. Very similiar to the Properties Search Bar at the top of the Properties area.

Step by step:

1. I select "Render Engine: Eevee" in my UIList.
2. I click the "show" operator beside the UIList.
3. Render Properties tab in Properties area opens and Render Engine: Eevee is highlighted.

Is there a way to implement that sort of behaviour with python?

Thank you for your help!